# Lost connection to main interface after brctl addif

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization, opennebula

I was setting up a server recently, and I was supposed to assign one of the public IP available for the server to a KVM guest. The server have the following setup:

eno1 - main internet connection of the host, assigned with a public ip
lo - loopback
virbr0 - bridge to virtual nic created by KVM

using Open Nebula I assigned virbr0 to the virtual network assigned to the guest machine and setup the specific config to the guest machine:

guest machine - /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
    address y.y.y.y
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    pointopoint <provided by host provider>
    gateway <provided by host provider>
```

finishing the guest configuration, I run the following on the host:

```
 brctl addif virbr0 eno1
```

After running this I was able to access the guest machine through the newly assigned IP. However, I can no longer access the host through SSH or Open Nebula.

Why does this happen? Is there also a way to setup virbr0 configuration on `/etc/network/interfaces` so it would stay persistent even when the host crashes?

Answer (score 1):

You need a bridge on the host. Let's say it has address x.x.x.x now.

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
   address x.x.x.x
   netmask <hostnetmask>
   gateway <hostgateway>
   bridge_ports eno1
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_maxwait 0
   bridge_fd 0
```

These are the settings to configure the network at boot.

If you have only have a single nic, reboot your host with these settings to activate the bridge. Or restart networking with [screen or tmux](https://serverfault.com/questions/278838/restarting-network-through-ssh).

If you have a dual nic setup, you don't need to reboot, simply SSH into your machine via the address on nic2 (eno2) and then

```
ifdown eno1
ip link add name br1 type bridge
ip link set dev br1 up
ip link set dev eno1 master br1
ip addr flush eno1
ifup eno1
```

Finally start your guest with the br1 network interface.

```
sudo kvm -net nic -net bridge,br=br1 ...
```

Comment: If  I apply x.x.x.x, which is my main server IP, to bridge network, will I still be able to ssh to the server?

Comment: Yes, you'll both have x.x.x.x for your host and y.y.y.y for your guest on a single interface. That's exactly what a bridge does. If you add your current host config to your question, I'll update the answer with the correct network settings.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait for the serial console access before trying, just to be safe. If things don't work, I'll post my host config.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the ip address on the bridge device "virbr0:

```
ip addr add y.y.y.y/32 dev virbr0
```

Look at the @stefaan-ghysels answer for details to configure at boot time.